# Call multiple functions stored in list

Tags: python

I have a program that I would like to automate, removing the pre-processing steps as much ass possible. Reading through a dataset, the program generates series of function calls that get used in a subsequent step. Currently I just copy the generated calls stored in the variable into the file, but I would like to skip this step if possible

````
##preprocessing steps here...
bindings = ["g.bind('rdf', URIRef('http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#'))",
 "g.bind('bf', URIRef('http://id.loc.gov/ontologies/bibframe/'))",
 "g.bind('bflc', URIRef('http://id.loc.gov/ontologies/bflc/'))"]

### then the bind calls are added to the function below.
g = rdflib.Graph()

g.bind('rdf', URIRef('http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#'))
g.bind('bf', URIRef('http://id.loc.gov/ontologies/bibframe/'))
g.bind('bflc', URIRef('http://id.loc.gov/ontologies/bflc/'))```

g.parse(data= graph, format='nt')
g.serialize(format='turtle')
````

How can I remove the copying and pasting from the process?

Comment: Essentially, you want to execute the _strings_ like `"g.bind('rdf', URIRef('http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#'))"` as if they contained valid Python code, right? This is exactly what you can do with [`eval` and `exec` functions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#eval).

Comment: I would avoid using `eval` or `exec` where they're not absolutely necessary. If you want to defer a function call until later, you can wrap it in a lambda, like `lambda: g.bind(...)`. However, there is probably no need for that here either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are these calls all going to be for the same function? If so, there is no need to store a string representing a function call; just store the data it should be called with.

```py
bindings = [
    ('rdf', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#'),
    ('bf', 'http://id.loc.gov/ontologies/bibframe/'),
    ('bflc', 'http://id.loc.gov/ontologies/bflc/'),
]

# ...

for key, uri in bindings:
    g.bind(key, URIRef(uri))
```